# Where CSS gets screen values?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm  informing about browser fingerprinting.

With javascript I can change and set screen resolution.

for example:

```
window.screen.__defineGetter__('width',function () {return 480;});
window.screen.__defineGetter__('height',function () {return 320;});
```

But if I use @media CSS3, I get the correct screen resolution (1600x900) of my pc:

```
@media screen and (min-device-height: 900px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

change color with 900 and less and not with 480 or less

I tried this code and not works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.screen.__defineGetter__('width',function () {return 480;});</script>
<style>
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
} 
@media screen and (min-device-height: 901px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is: What I have to change to get that CSS read 480 instead 900?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: why would you want to get a value which is different from the real value? Smells of a nasty workaround or an X/Y problem. And the browser's internal CSS doesn't use your in-page JS functions to detect the screen size anyway. What you write in the page stays in the page, it doesn't affect the internal rendering engine. I notice also you haven't defined `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">` which would give you a consistent viewport on all devices.

Comment: @JLRishe reading a code that mask some variables used to get fingerprint key I noticed `defineGetter`  method and I thought about the CSS way to get the screen resolution.